# Change panda series to an int

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following code:

```
x1 = df[(df['event_name'] == 'Listen') & (df['cell'] == 'CONTROL')].yes_user_count
y1 = df[(df['event_name'] == 'Listen') & (df['cell'] != 'CONTROL')].yes_user_count

x_n = df[(df['event_name'] == 'Listen') & (df['cell'] == 'CONTROL')].total_user_count
y_n = df[(df['event_name'] == 'Listen') & (df['cell'] != 'CONTROL')].total_user_count

zscore, pval = proportions_ztest([x1, y1], [x_n, y_n])
```

However, the ztest function does not work. The reason looks to be x1, y1, x_n, and y_n are panda series. I tried to use x1.astype(int) but it does not seem to solve the problem.

Can someone please advise what's the best solution to this?

Comment: Use `.values` after x1...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want `.tolist()`:

```
x1 = df[(df['event_name'] == 'Listen') & (df['cell'] == 'CONTROL')].yes_user_count.tolist()
y1 = df[(df['event_name'] == 'Listen') & (df['cell'] != 'CONTROL')].yes_user_count.tolist()

x_n = df[(df['event_name'] == 'Listen') & (df['cell'] == 'CONTROL')].total_user_count.tolist()
y_n = df[(df['event_name'] == 'Listen') & (df['cell'] != 'CONTROL')].total_user_count.tolist()

zscore, pval = proportions_ztest([x1, y1], [x_n, y_n])
```

But also i would recommend using `loc` with column name as second value:

```
x1 = df.loc[(df['event_name'] == 'Listen') & (df['cell'] == 'CONTROL'), 'yes_user_count'].tolist()
y1 = df.loc[(df['event_name'] == 'Listen') & (df['cell'] != 'CONTROL'), 'yes_user_count'].tolist()

x_n = df.loc[(df['event_name'] == 'Listen') & (df['cell'] == 'CONTROL'), 'total_user_count'].tolist()
y_n = df.loc[(df['event_name'] == 'Listen') & (df['cell'] != 'CONTROL'), 'total_user_count'].tolist()

zscore, pval = proportions_ztest([x1, y1], [x_n, y_n])
```

Or even better:

```
mask1 = (df['event_name'] == 'Listen') & (df['cell'] == 'CONTROL')
mask2 = (df['event_name'] == 'Listen') & (df['cell'] != 'CONTROL')
x1 = df.loc[mask1, 'yes_user_count'].tolist()
y1 = df.loc[mask2, 'yes_user_count'].tolist()

x_n = df.loc[mask1, 'total_user_count'].tolist()
y_n = df.loc[mask2, 'total_user_count'].tolist()

zscore, pval = proportions_ztest([x1, y1], [x_n, y_n])
```

Comment: Thank you! Why would tolist() work but not astype(int)

Comment: @RJL Because that just converts them to integers, when they already are, so my code makes it a list, which works, don't forget to accept it if it works :-)

Comment: @RJL Happy to help, :-)